# how to force showing login window with windows intergrated autentication

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, security, iis

I have an silverlight application configured with windows integrated security.

I would like to emulate the "Sign in as different user" functionality

I would like to give the user, the option to click a button and show the
windows authentication login window, so that the user can enter the "User
name" and "Password" again using another domain account.

Is this possible and how?

(btw i found this question on another site but with no answers, I need the same thing so i copy/pasted a bit)

Answer (score 0):

That's only doable if your ASP.NET application sends back 401.2 challenge to the browser. but the details are too complex, and you should avoid that if possible.

Forms authentication is a better option.

Comment: yes, but forms authentication is not an option here. I must use intergrated